# android 2D array without using split method

Tags: android, android-resources, arrays

I have a 2D array in string resources. I want to use it without using the java split method (I am assuming the time complexity of split is bigger). Here is my array:

```
<string-array name="my_stuff">   
<item>
    <name>car</name>
    <number>12</number>
 </item>  
 <item> 
    <name>comic books</name>
    <number>32</number>
...
```

so if I read this array using TypedArray, how do I retrieve the elements?

By not wanting to use `split` I mean:

If I store the array as

```
<string-array name="my_stuff">   
<item>car,12</item>  
 <item> comic books,32</item>
...
```

Then I could use split to parse the elements.

Comment: How big is your array that you're worried about the time complexity of split?

Comment: see my elaboration on `split`

Comment: This looks like a 1D array of objects with multiple properties. Is there a second dimension that I'm missing?  If you wanted to retrieve something from the array, would it require two indices (`array[x][y]`)?

Answer (score 0):

The overhead of using `TypedArray` is way bigger than a call to `String.split()` to parse a simple `String`.